# Springboot Webflux + Reactjs Events onmessage is not able to fetch messages when using setupProxy.js as proxy url from Ui to backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, okta, http-proxy-middleware

I am using http-proxy-middleware in my reactApp.
Backend is implemented in Springboot .
Springboot Webflux is being used to send the Flux data to UI .

When I am directly using

```
eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
      };
```

I am able to see the messages.
But when I am using

```
const apiURL = "/test"
eventSource = new EventSource(apiURL);
```

Then I am not able to see the messages.
my setupProxy.js includes

```
  const proxied =
    pathname.match("^/test") ;
  return proxied;
};


module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use([
    createProxyMiddleware(apiFilter, { target: apiUrlTest, ws: true }),
  ]);
};
```

Is there any way to resolve it. Why on direct call i m getting messages but when calling through proxy I am not able to view the message.